# Is There Any Way To Remove This From My Car?

Tags: ford

I crashed my car into a wall, and now this white stuff is stuck on my car. I’m almost certain it isn’t the paint, the white stuff is peeling b[image]ut some parts just won’t budge

Comment: Try T-cut in a small area. Of course, if that's not paint but has exposed the plastic, it won't come off.

Comment: Is the wall now red?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like you've scrubbed the paint off back to the undercoat, and in some places back to the plastic underneath the undercoat. You cannot 'remove' it, but a body shop can re-spray the affected area.

Comment: You say "re-spray", but that's going to take more work then a re-spray. Just saying.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 given the quality of the question, it wasn't worth going into significant effort on an answer.

Comment: Reciprocating a poor question with a poor answer is good? While this answers the basis of the question, giving the OP what they need to do the job might just help not only the OP, but also might just help out someone else who needs it. Our purpose here on Stack Exchange is to bring/keep information. We appreciate you being here and answering questions ... please remember our goal when all is said and done.

Comment: Feel free to add a more detailed answer, with all the steps required to do the repair at home.